# Given vector $v=3i+4j$ and force vector $\vec F=0.2\vec i-0.5\vec j$, find the component of $\vec F$ parallel to $\vec v$.

Tags: vectors

The solution is $-0.168\vec i-0.224\vec j$. I have the formula $F_{||}=(F•u)u$ and $\vec F=\vec F_{||}+\vec F_{\perp}$, but I am not sure how to relate these to v.

Comment: Projection, you know the formula?

Comment: @Nameless Yes... Projection of v onto the unit vector of F?

Comment: Right, so in your formula, $u = v$, and don't forget to normalize your vector $v.$

Comment: @Nameless This works, thank you much!

Answer (score -2):

Dear Emily projection of $F$ on $v~$: $F_{v} =\frac{F.v}{v.v}\frac{v}{|v|}=-\frac{1.4}{125}v$

Comment: Check your formula. There's one too many $\displaystyle |\vec v|$ on the denominator. It should be $(\vec F \cdot \hat {\vec v})\hat{\vec v} = (\frac{\vec F \cdot \vec v}{\vec v \cdot \vec v})\vec v$ and the answer should be $\displaystyle-\frac{1.4}{25}\vec v$.